# VS 2017 generating runtimes folder when running the app

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have asp.net mvc app in VS 2017, whenever I run the app, there is a runtimes folder get generated, and also when I publish the app, same folder is copied to the Publish folder.

I don't know what I did in recent months that made it to get generated, it was not there few months back, and suddenly it started to appear.

Anyway to identify what is generating it and stop that?